# Maxima of random variables defined on unit interval

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that for each $t \in (0, 1]$, I define 
$X_t \sim N(0, 1)$, independently. Is it true that 
$$
P\left(\sup_{t \leq T} X_t \leq \alpha\right) = P(X_1 \leq \alpha)^T, 
$$
for all $0 < T \leq 1$? Basically I wonder if this kind of independence property holds for random variables indexed on a continuous set.

Comment: Actually the set $\left(\sup_{t\leq T}X_t\right)$ might not be Borel measurable, because there are uncountably many random variables involved. But if you make the trajectory of those random variables continuous over time, then this set is measurable, as done in case of Brownian motion. Construction of such a non-measurable set is not very easy.

Comment: $\sup_{t \le T} X_t \le \alpha$ is closed (an arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed), so in particular it is Borel for the product topology on $\mathbb R^{(0,1]}$.

Comment: It seems you are treating an interval size $T$ as if it were an integer number of independent quantities.

Comment: @Michael you're right. In fact that was my question: can I treat it the same way I'd be able to if I had $1, 2, \dots, T$ random variables. The example Robert gives below says, in general, no.

Comment: @RobertIsrael How is $\{\omega:\sup_{t \le T} X_t(\omega) \le \alpha\}$ a Borel set if we know nothing about the underlying prob. space. Do you mean that $(X_t)$ is a kind of "canonical process"?

Comment: I'm assuming $\{\omega: X_t(\omega) \le \alpha\}$ is closed for each $t$, as it is if $X_t$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  If you have infinitely many iid $X_t$, for any $\alpha$ such that $P(X_t > \alpha) > 0$, then almost surely some $X_t > \alpha$, i.e. $P(\sup_t X_t \le \alpha) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset (0,1]$. Then

\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}^{*}\!\left(\sup_{t \leq T} X_t \leq \alpha\right)&\le \mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\{X_{x_n}\le \alpha\}\right)
=\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcap_{1\le n\le m}\{X_{x_n}\le \alpha\}\right)  \\ &\overset{(1)}{=}\lim_{m\to\infty}[\mathsf{P}(X_1\le \alpha)]^m=0,
\end{align}

where $(1)$ follows from the i.i.d. assumption.