# An elementary question on a stochastic process with "constant" distribution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $ X=(X_t)_{t \in T} $ with $ X_t: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ for all $ t \in T=[0,t_{\max}] $ a stochastic process satisfying $ X_t \stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{=} X_0 $ (e.g., a normal distribution with parameters $ \mu $ and $ \Sigma $) for all $ t \in T $.

Do we have $ P\left[ \bigcap_{t \in T} \lbrace c^\top X_t > C\rbrace \right] = P[c^\top X_0 > C] $ for all vectors $ c \in \mathbb{R}^n $? Or do we need any further assumptions?

Can we just state $ \bigcap_{t \in T} \lbrace c^\top X_t > C\rbrace = \lbrace c^\top X_0 > C \rbrace $ since the distribution of $ X_t $ does not change over time? (How would a formal proof look like?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the event $\bigcap_{t \in T} \lbrace c^\top X_t > C\rbrace$ may not be measurable when $T$ is an uncountable index set. Second, your assertion need not hold even if $T=\{0,1
\}$, e.g. $X_0$ and $X_1$ are independent $N(0,1)$ so that for any $C\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(X_0>C,X_1>C)=[\mathsf{P}(X_0>C)]^2<\mathsf{P}(X_0>C).
$$

Comment: Ok. Would the measurability problem be solved, if $ \bigcup_{t \in T} $ is used instead of $ \bigcap_{t \in T} $? And is there some way to compute this probability? Can we for instance find $ P\left[\bigcup_{t \in T} \lbrace \sum_k X_k > C \rbrace \right] $?

Comment: Sorry, it should be something like $ \sum_{k=1}^n (X_t)_k $ is the previous comment.

Comment: See. for example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105547/maxima-of-random-variables-defined-on-unit-interval/3105638#3105638).

Comment: Basically, you need to know the law of the process $(X_t)$ to determine that probability.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!